# How do you place a map as an interactive background in d3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working with a few circles in d3.js (nodes of a Sankey graph), each of which contain location data, (country,city,state,latitude,longitude,etc). The goal is the have Google Maps (or a world map in general) zoom in on a location behind the clicked circle (as if the circle is the marker). I just think it would be a pretty cool feature to add if it is possible. Any help would be really appreciated.

Ex) So, if my circle is positioned at (x,y), then the location of the map would be there also, and zoomed in on the location specified. So, a really ugly example would by the graph displayed behind my node for Melbourne.

[image]

Comment: you want zoom in when  click a marker ?

Comment: Yes, ideally, the background would start out in a world view, and then zoom in when we click on a marker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a listener on marker

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  map.setZoom(18);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```

see  this for a simple sample https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple